# Getting an error 1064 from a WITH but it works without it

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression, mysql-error-1064

"Incorrect syntax" when using a common table expression

```
WITH a AS
(
SELECT *
FROM student_table_name
WHERE student_id=6639352
ORDER BY modified DESC
)
SELECT * FROM a
```

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax

It works without the

```
(
)
SELECT * FROM a
```

but when im running the inner query everything works!
somehow the "with" command dont act like it should do..

Comment: It acts as it should in version 8 or greater, what version are you on?

Comment: CTE was added in MySQL 8.x, you get a syntax error with 5.x.

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return?

Comment: It’s 5.7. Thank you all so much!!!! Solved.